# How do i get the frequency of the given array?

Tags: java

I need to find out how many times these numbers appear in an array by replacing it with a " * ", but it gives so much stars.
Does anyone have suggestions to help me solve this please.
This is what i have

```
public class Frequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] rateFrequency = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ":");

            for (int j = 0; j <= rateFrequency.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: You missing a if somewhere, not giving it as an asnwer, tip: it is in the second loop

Comment: will the input array always be sorted, as shown here? will 4 always be the max value? should values with zero stars be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that for each number (0-3) you iterate over the array and print a star every time an item is the same as the current number.

You can make it better by iterating over the array first to find the extent of the range of numbers.

A possible alternative would be to add the numbers to a `Multiset` (e.g. from Google's [Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) libraries) which can automatically tell you the count of any item.

I've included some example code below. Obviously, don't look at this code until you have tried to write it yourself!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] rateFrequency = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };

    int maxNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rateFrequency.length; i++) {
        maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, rateFrequency[i]);
    }

    for (int num = 0; num <= maxNum; num++) {
        System.out.print(num + ": ");

        for (int i = 0; i < rateFrequency.length; i++) {
            if (rateFrequency[i] == num) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Produces:

> 0:  *
>   1:  *
>   2:  *  *  *
>   3:  *  *

If you want to avoid `Math.max()` you can write the equivalent code yourself:

```
int maxNum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rateFrequency.length; i++) {
    int num = rateFrequency[i];
    if (num > maxNum) {
        maxNum = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Math operation the only way i could do this? that the only part i do not seem to understand... probably have to do my research better...Thank you for your time

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you how to avoid it.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: note: the original code printed values from 0 to 4. this one prints values from 0 to n, where n is max value from the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Collections.frequency() method:

```
Integer[] rateFrequency = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 }; 
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(rateFrequency);

for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
    System.out.println(i+":" + Collections.frequency(list,i));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0:1
1:1
2:3
3:2
4:0
```

You can modify it to print "*" by creating another loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this question with **hashing**. You can keep count of each number in an array then print **"*"** as many times as it exists in the array.

> Base of an array as number and value in each base as a frequency of the number.

```
public class Frequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] rateFrequency = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 }; 
        int[] keepCount = new int[rateFrequency.length]; //to keep frequency of each number

        for(int i=0; i<rateFrequency.length; i++) 
            keepCount[rateFrequency[i]]++; //counting the frequency of each number

        for(int i=0; i<rateFrequency.length; i++) {
            if(keepCount[i] > 0)
                System.out.print(i + ": ");

            while(keepCount[i] > 0) {
                System.out.print("*"); //printing frequency in terms of *
                keepCount[i]--; //decreasing the count 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 0: *
>
> 1: *
>
> 2: ***
>
> 3: **

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Assuming that the input array will always be sorted, and that values with zero stars don't need to be printed, one could use this type of loop:

```
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
int pos = 0;
while(pos < arr.length) {
    int current = arr[pos];
    System.out.print(current + ":");
    do {
        System.out.print(" *");
        ++pos;
    } while(pos < arr.length && arr[pos] == current);
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

> 0: *
>
> 1: *
>
> 2: * * *
>
> 3: * *

**Option 2:**

If, however, you need to print all the values for a given range (e.g. 0-4), even when they would have zero stars, then I would use something like this (again, this code is assuming a sorted input array):

```
final int RANGE = 4;
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
int pos = 0;
for(int n=0; n <= RANGE; ++n) {
    System.out.print(n + ":");
    while(pos < arr.length && arr[pos] == n) {
        System.out.print(" *");
        ++pos;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

> 0: *
>
> 1: *
>
> 2: * * *
>
> 3: * *
>
> 4:

Comment: Right, and you could always sort the input array, if it's not guaranteed already to be sorted, using `Arrays.sort(arr)`.

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can find the range by looking at the last item.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ see my note on your answer, regarding that point. unfortunately the OP never responded to my request for clarification on her question.

Comment: Thank you, i went through everyone solutions, i appreciate it very much... my question was answered perfectly . and now i actually understand the different type of ways to do it

Comment: @Patric Parker Thank you